# How to prevent .NET JSON feeds from being cached

Tags: jquery, .net, json, iis, jsonp

I have created simple .aspx page which queries a database for some live data and then returns a JSONP (or at last a JSONP-like) feed of `Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8`

Here is the format of the output, more or less:

```
jsonp1307643489579([
  ["12345","Text Here","99999","More Text Here","True","False","7/31","1"...],
  ["12345","Text Here","99999","More Text There",...]
]
```

Then comes a JQuery .getJSON call:

```
var url = "myURL.aspx?id=123&callBack=?";
$.getJSON(url, null, function(msg) { etc etc.
```

It all works fine except for the following.   In my development environment and on my local server, fresh data come back live every time.  But on the production web server, the data stubbornly caches until I recycle the IIS application pool (!)

Some things I have tried without success.

1/ cache: false in ajaxSetup didn't work.

2/ Turned off output caching in the web.config.

2a/ OutputCache Location="None" in the aspx page declarations doesn't do it.

3/ Added random unique querystring data to the .getJSON(url) call.  Seeing as how we are appending a unique callback param to each call, I guess this was already happening anyway.

Any idea why my web server is holding on to these cached application/JSON files?

**EDIT:**  i am viewing the actual .aspx feeds as they come down from the web server, and they are cached there.  So to my understanding, it's a web server caching issue and not necessarily a JQUERY caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was indeed the .ASPX server page caching the data.  For all of the focus on the client-side AJAX stuff, I overlooked the obvious.

So I added a litany of preventative measures on the server side (Response.ExpiresAbsolute, et cetera) and it did the job.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable. If you find your own answer, others can benefit from what you found. It's even okay to post a question *in order to* answer your own question, if you think you've found something that's either hard to find normally or isn't on SO.

Comment: could you please explain this in detail? A response telling me you did "et cetera" doesn't really help

Answer (score 10):

Before you make any `getJSON` calls, use this:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   cache: false
});
```

I battled this same issue for about a half hour yesterday. I'm not sure why manually adding a random query string wouldn't work, but this solved the issue for me. Cache hits were completely random until I added the general setup above.

Comment: I have tried this, with no luck.  I'll make an edit to my OP to specify that I'm actually viewing the .aspx feeds directly in notepad, and they're coming from the server as cached versions, irrespective of whether or not JQUERY is involved.  Perhaps I should retag this as an IIS question too.

Comment: Works like a charm, my AJAX request is no longer cached and I get a fresh result every time. If it doesn't work, just add a random number to the end of the request (or a timestamp) and it will be considered a unique request and not fetched from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Stefan's answer, setting cache to false tells jquery to append a random query string to make the request unique.

Example: myURL.aspx?id=123&callBack=&**_=13245897565132154878**